# Crash when launch camera android permission

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-permissions

I'm using imported [Scalibrary module](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo) sample app for image processing filter.
It has two main button open camera and open gallery.

It's working fine on android Kitkat but when I try to launch the camera on android 9 It crash

I have tried adding : `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` on manifest but no luck

Note : I have already given permission camera and external write read storage on 
manifest

Update : Apparently I have to make the permission pop up for it to works because Im currently enabling it manually in the settings how do I do that ?

What Im I missing ?

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.documentscanner/com.scanlibrary.ScanActivity}: java.lang. 
SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.
CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.scanlibrary.provider/external_files/scanSample/IMG_20191230_065113.jpg} (has extras) } from 
ProcessRecord{6bafaa3 13455:com.example.documentscanner/u0a140} (pid=13455, uid=10140) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.
camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.scanlibrary.provider/external_files/scanSample/IMG_20191230_065113.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{6bafaa3 13455:com.example.documentscanner/u0a140} (pid=13455, uid=10140) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.openCamera(PickImageFragment.java:129)
    at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.handleIntentPreference(PickImageFragment.java:77)
    at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.init(PickImageFragment.java:58)
    at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.onCreateView(PickImageFragment.java:48)
```

**PickImageFragment**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pick_image_fragment, null);
    init();
    return view;
}

private void init() {
    cameraButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new CameraButtonClickListener());
    if (isIntentPreferenceSet()) {
        handleIntentPreference();
    } else {
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}

private void handleIntentPreference() {
    int preference = getIntentPreference();
    if (preference == ScanConstants.OPEN_CAMERA) {
        openCamera();
    } else if (preference == ScanConstants.OPEN_MEDIA) {
        openMediaContent();
    }
}

public void openCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File file = createImageFile();
    boolean isDirectoryCreated = file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    Log.d("", "openCamera: isDirectoryCreated: " + isDirectoryCreated);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Uri tempFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                "com.scanlibrary.provider", // As defined in Manifest
                file);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempFileUri);
    } else {
        Uri tempFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempFileUri);
    }
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, ScanConstants.START_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: You have to request *Runtime Permission* and get approval from user in API 24 and up. Check more here: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions

Comment: Open camera only after checking if permission is already granted or not. If not ask for the permission first.

Comment: @Rohit5k2  How do I pop up permission on start for camera ?

Comment: Please check the post I have marked and link shared by @Md.Asaduzzaman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can use these permission in your manifest file with other permission,

```
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
android:required="false" />
```

Comment: As I said I have already given theses permission